# Filter values only if not null using lambda in Java8

Tags: java, lambda, nullpointerexception, null, java-8

I have a list of objects say `car`. I want to filter this list based on some parameter using Java 8. But if the parameter is `null`, it throws `NullPointerException`. How to filter out null values?

Current code is as follows

```
requiredCars = cars.stream().filter(c -> c.getName().startsWith("M"));
```

This throws `NullPointerException` if `getName()` returns `null`.

Comment: Do you wanna “filter values only if not null” or “filter out null values”? That sounds contradicting to me.

Comment: Could I suggest that you accept [Tunaki's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32884225/42473) as it appears to be the only one which actually answers your question.

Comment: What about kotlin? ))
requiredCars = cars.filter {c -> c?.name?.startsWith("M"))};

Answer (score 519):

In this particular example, I think @Tagir is 100% correct get it into one filter and do the two checks.  I wouldn't use `Optional.ofNullable` the Optional stuff is really for return types not to be doing logic... but really neither here nor there.

I wanted to point out that `java.util.Objects` has a nice method for this in a broad case, so you can do this:

```javascript
    cars.stream()
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
```

Which will clear out your null objects.  For anyone not familiar, that's the short-hand for the following:

```javascript
    cars.stream()
        .filter(car -> Objects.nonNull(car))
```

To partially answer the question at hand to return the list of car names that starts with `"M"`:

```javascript
    cars.stream()
        .filter(car -> Objects.nonNull(car))
        .map(car -> car.getName())
        .filter(carName -> Objects.nonNull(carName))
        .filter(carName -> carName.startsWith("M"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Once you get used to the shorthand lambdas you could also do this:

```javascript
    cars.stream()
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .map(Car::getName)        // Assume the class name for car is Car
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .filter(carName -> carName.startsWith("M"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Unfortunately once you `.map(Car::getName)` you'll only be returning the list of names, not the cars.  So less beautiful but fully answers the question:

```javascript
    cars.stream()
        .filter(car -> Objects.nonNull(car))
        .filter(car -> Objects.nonNull(car.getName()))
        .filter(car -> car.getName().startsWith("M"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: note that the null car isn't the issue. In this case, it's name property causing problems. So `Objects::nonNull` can't be used here, and in last advice it should be `cars.stream()
    .filter(car -> Objects.nonNull(car.getName()))` I believe

Comment: BTW, I think `cars.stream()
    .filter(car -> Objects.nonNull(car.getName()) && car.getName().startsWith("M"))` would be the summary of your advice in this question context

Comment: @kiedysktos That's a good point that calling `.startWith` could also cause a null pointer.  The point I was trying to make is that Java supplies a method specifically for filtering out null objects from your streams.

Comment: @Mark Booth yes, obviously `Objects.nonNull` is equivalent to `!= null`, your option is shorter

Comment: Aren't you creating a list of car names (`String`) instead cars (`Car`)?

Comment: Definitely right, once you map to `getName` it's just a list of Strings.  I'll update the answer.  Thank you!

Comment: It's more efficient to use the method reference Objects:nonNull (first option) than using the arrow operator that instance an object.

Answer (score 91):

You just need to filter the cars that have a `null` name:

```
requiredCars = cars.stream()
                   .filter(c -> c.getName() != null)
                   .filter(c -> c.getName().startsWith("M"));
```

Comment: It's a real shame that this answer isn't more highly voted as it appears to be the only answer that actually answers the question.

Comment: @MarkBooth The question "How to filter out null values?" seems to be answered well by xbakesx.

Comment: @MarkBooth Looking at the dates you are correct. My mistake.

Comment: Performance wise is it good to filter the stream twice Or better use the predicate for filtering? Just want to know.

Answer (score 68):

The proposed answers are great. Just would like to suggest an improvement to handle the case of `null` list using `Optional.ofNullable`, [new feature in Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html):

```javascript
List<String> carsFiltered = Optional.ofNullable(cars)
                    .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)
                    .stream()
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So, the full answer will be:

```javascript
List<String> carsFiltered = Optional.ofNullable(cars)
                    .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)
                    .stream()
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull) //filtering car object that are null
                    .map(Car::getName) //now it's a stream of Strings
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull) //filtering null in Strings
                    .filter(name -> name.startsWith("M"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()); //back to List of Strings
```

Comment: Bad use of Optional.  null should never be used as a synonym for an empty Collection in the first place.

Comment: @VGR Of course, but that is not what happens in practice. Sometimes (most of the time) you need to work with code that a lot of people worked on. Sometime you receive your data from external interfaces. For all those cases, Optional is a great use.

Comment: note that the null car isn't the issue. In this case, it's name property causing problems. So `Objects::nonNull` doesn't solve the problem since non-null car can have name==null

Comment: Of course @kiedysktos, but that's not what I wanted to show in the answer. But, I'm accepting what you saying and editing the answer :)

Answer (score 32):

You can do this in single filter step:

```
requiredCars = cars.stream().filter(c -> c.getName() != null && c.getName().startsWith("M"));
```

If you don't want to call `getName()` several times (for example, it's expensive call), you can do this:

```
requiredCars = cars.stream().filter(c -> {
    String name = c.getName();
    return name != null && name.startsWith("M");
});
```

Or in more sophisticated way:

```
requiredCars = cars.stream().filter(c -> 
    Optional.ofNullable(c.getName()).filter(name -> name.startsWith("M")).isPresent());
```

Comment: The inline expansion in the second example was valuable for my use case

Answer (score 4):

you can use this

```
List<Car> requiredCars = cars.stream()
    .filter (t->  t!= null && StringUtils.startsWith(t.getName(),"M"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4):

Leveraging the power of `java.util.Optional#map()`:

```
List<Car> requiredCars = cars.stream()
  .filter (car -> 
    Optional.ofNullable(car)
      .map(Car::getName)
      .map(name -> name.startsWith("M"))
      .orElse(false) // what to do if either car or getName() yields null? false will filter out the element
    )
  .collect(Collectors.toList())
;
```

Comment: Using the complexity of Optional to replace a simple boolean expression is bad practice imho.