# Avoiding a java.lang.NullPointerException being thrown while performing arithmetic operations on a collection of values using lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda, nullpointerexception, java-8

Given a list of values to sum up.

```
List<CartItems> cartItems = ...

BigDecimal totalWeight = cartItems.stream().reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, (weight, cart)
        -> weight.add(cart.getProduct().getWeight().multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(cart.getQty()))), BigDecimal::add)
        .setScale(SCALE, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Here, `cart.getProduct().getWeight()` may be `null` at anytime, since it is an optional field. This will thus throw a `java.lang.NullPointerException`, if one of the items contains a `null` value in the `weight` field of type `java.math.BigDecmial`.

What is the most concise way to avoid a `java.lang.NullPointerException` being thrown when an item in a given collection contains a `null` value other than imposing a nasty conditional check like the following?

```
BigDecimal totalWeight = products.stream().reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, (weight, cart)
        -> weight.add(cart.getProduct().getWeight() == null ? BigDecimal.ZERO : cart.getProduct().getWeight().multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(cart.getQty()))), BigDecimal::add)
        .setScale(SCALE, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Similarly, the following will also throw a `java.lang.NullPointerException`, since the given list contains a `null` value in it.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
        add(1);
        add(2);
        add(3);
        add(null);
        add(5);
    }};

Integer sum = list.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum); // Or
//Integer sum = list.stream().reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b);

System.out.println("sum : " + sum);
```

Comment: What do you want to happen when a null is encountered? Do you just want to filter them out? Like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32884225/1743880?

Comment: you can filter out nulls from the stream with `.filter(Objects::nonNull)`

Comment: Define nasty? Is `Optional.ofNullable(...).map(...).orElse(0)` nasty?

Comment: @Tiny adding zero is an empty operation. you could just skip it altogether using filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is more with the reduce. You try to do to many things in one function. As I understand it, you want the sum of `weight*qty` for each cart. I would cut the operation like this:

```
BigDecimal totalWeight = cartItems.stream()
        .filter(cart -> cart != null
                && cart.getProduct() != null 
                && cart.getProduct().getWeight() != null)
        .map(cart -> cart.getProduct().getWeight().multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(cart.getQty())))
        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)
        .setScale(SCALE, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Comment: This is not the problem in this case but what if `cart` itself or `cart.getProduct()` returns `null` before `getWeight()` is referenced?

Comment: you can chain more `filter`, or you can test more things in the `filter`: `filter(cart -> cart != null && cart.getProduct() != null && cart.getProduct().getWeight() != null)`

Answer (score 1):

Here are couple of solutions for this problem.

```
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{
                1,
                2,
                3,
                (Integer)null,
                5,
        });

        Integer sum = list.stream().map(i -> i != null ? i : 0).reduce(0, Integer::sum);
```

Or

```
list.replaceAll(s -> s == null ? 0 : s);
Integer sum = list.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum);
```

Comment: Yes it can but technically it doesn't answer the question. The OP wants to replace null values with 0. Suppose you have multiplication instead of addition. Then 1 null value and the result is 0, when here, you filter it out.

Comment: Yes thats right. I just saw his comments  that it should be considered 0 . my appologies

Comment: Especially, I dislike this kind of conditional checks `a != null` or `a == null` every time an object is to be referenced.

Comment: filtering is the same, as you get an element in your sum that is 0 with your ternary.

Comment: I have replaced the filter with  with replace the value based on condition.
another way could be   calling  list.replaceAll(s -> s == null ? 0 : s); before the actual intended operation .

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
Integer sum = list.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).reduce(0, Integer::sum);
```

Bye!