# How to avoid NPE in below case?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, comparator

```
List<User> sortedList = userList.stream()       
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(User::getAge).reversed())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

sortedList.forEach(System.out::println)
```

In the above case if User is null it is giving NPE. How to avoid NPE here?

Comment: What should the result be when `AnyObj` is null? How should those values compare to others in the list?

Comment: Also: consider whether there is a good reason to allow null values to exist in the list in the first place.

Comment: Is this really valid syntax for a comparator lambda?

Comment: Maybe this answer helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32884195/filter-values-only-if-not-null-using-lambda-in-java8 - you can filter the null values in the list before sorting it

Comment: @GhostCat I haven't used Java in a long time and had to look up the new features; but I'm pretty sure that's meant to be either `AnyObj -> AnyObj.getAttr()`, or `AnyObj::getAttr`.

Comment: I agree with Karl ... this really doesn't look like valid Java syntax. Please: be diligent about your input. You want other people to spend their free time to help you with your problem for free. So please spend the 1 minute it takes to show us REAL legit java code, not something "pseudo" that you BELIEVE communicates your intent.

Comment: And yes, nulls can be filtered out before ... but the question is: is that what the OP wants?! So the real question is something only the OP can answer: what are the requirements. Why are there nulls in the list, and more importantly, how should sorting affect those null values?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I got the solution.
It is very easy. Just use stream. filter(a->a!=null)...

```
List<User> sortedList = userList.stream()
    .filter(a->a!=null)       
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(User::getAge).reversed())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

sortedList.forEach(System.out::println)
```